# How do I define a SemgrexPattern in Stanford API, to match nodes' text without using {lemma:...}?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am working with the edu.stanford.nlp.semgrex and edu.stanford.nlp.tress.semgraph packages and am looking for a way to match nodes with a text value other than the lemma: directive.

I couldn't find all possible attribute names in javadoc for SemgrexPattern, only those for lemma, tag, and relational operators - is there a comprehensive list available?

For example, in the following sentence
   My take-home pay is $20.

extracting the 'take-home' node is not possible using

```
(SemgrexPattern.compile( "{lemma:take-home}"))
.matcher( "My take-home pay is $20.").find()
```

yields false, because take-home is deemed not to be a lemma.

What do I need to do to match nodes with non-lemma, arbitrary text?

Thanks for any advice or comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I realize that `{word:take-home}` would work in the example above.

Thanks..